# How to make a scipy array from custom data format?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, ipython

Warning: Python newbie...

I have text that looks like this, which came from a database query:

```
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";416765.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF ARTS AND SCIENCES";36000.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";2000.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";179728.0
2000;"OTHER DOMESTIC HIGHER EDUCATION";244547.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";107325.0
2000;"OTHER DOMESTIC HIGHER EDUCATION";61609.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";93600.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF EARTH SCIENCES/NATURAL RESOURCES";64865.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";50000.0
...
```

I'd like to make a chart that shows the average award amount for all years with error bars for each Division.

However, I'm not sure how to get this data into a scipy array to make the chart. I've tried the following:

```
data = asarray(2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";416765.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF ARTS AND SCIENCES";36000.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";2000.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";179728.0
    2000;"OTHER DOMESTIC HIGHER EDUCATION";244547.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";107325.0
    2000;"OTHER DOMESTIC HIGHER EDUCATION";61609.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";93600.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF EARTH SCIENCES/NATURAL RESOURCES";64865.0
    2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";50000.0)
```

I also tried with `data = sp.array()`. Both give the following error:

```
    data = sp.asarray(2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";416765.0
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, it seems to me that the `array()` and `asarray()` methods don't like semi-colon delimited data.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great. If possible, I'd prefer not to save the data to a file first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for data like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input = """2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";416765.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF ARTS AND SCIENCES";36000.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";2000.0
2000;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";179728.0
2001;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";1234.0
2001;"SCHOOLS OF ARTS AND SCIENCES";100.0
2002;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";9999.0
2002;"SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE";8436.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input), sep=';', header=None, names=['year', 'division', 'award'])
print df
yeartotals = df.groupby(['year'])[['award']].sum()
print yeartotals
yeartotals.plot()
plt.show()
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to plot, but [pandas integrates quite nicely with matplotlib for plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).